# Как скрыть вызовы API с сайта

Tags: vue.js, axios, xhr

Возможно ли скрыть вызовы API на сервер в Network-e(Devtools). Если на примере сайта, то вот https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=37514. Здесь, чтобы отобразить текст книги, нужно же откуда-то его брать. Однако, я не могу найти в Networks получение этих данных.

Comment: На указанном сайте для получения следующей страницы используется просто переход с указанием номера страницы: ```<a class="lt12" href="/br/?b=37514&amp;p=4">Следующая страница</a>```. И никакого API.

Comment: ок, переход будет сделан, но на той странице данные тоже же нужно откуда-то брать, разве нет? Вот, у меня вопрос откуда берут если не приходит по апи

Comment: Новая страница полностью генерится на сервере. Дополнительного обмена данными не нужно.

Comment: благодарю, поняла